# Call SOAP API with NTLM authentication from webapp / javascript

Tags: javascript, soap, windows-authentication, ntlm

I am creating a vuejs webapp and need to request data from an existing soap webservice with NTLM authentication. I have found some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660995/consuming-soap-service-with-ntlm-authentication) e.g. with [ntlm.js](https://github.com/erlandranvinge/ntlm.js/tree/master) how to do that, but it seems that the user credentials are always needed (all the code snippets I found had username, password & domain as required parameters for the ntlm auth process).

Is there a way that the browser can access the NTLM data (e.g. hash?)/credentials of the current user in order to request data from the api (-> without asking for the credentials again?)

I am able to query the api by SoapUI (which offers an integrated NTLM auth feature -> but I need to provide username, password & domain).

As a fallback I would access the api via my main app backend (!=soap service server) with a static user. But I would not be able to see the user who made the request in my logs (therefore not the preferred way to go).

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with NTLM.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thank you some much 
Best Regards
Simon